# Unity with repositories

Tags: c#, wpf, unity-container, ioc-container

I'm new to the Unity IoC (DI in general) and have read a lot of the documents and watched several hour long videos on Channel 9. Even after all of that, I didn't find any example that demonstrated a feature set in looking for.

Everything online showed that you can create a repository, and register it with a unity container. Then I can inject the repository into my view model constructors. In my particular app, I need to support ParseCloud, Box, DropBox and OneDrive, along with multiple implementations of an interface. So I planned on creating four repositories, one for each service.

Does it make more sense to have Unity register a single abstract repository factory, that the view models can use to fetch the correct repository based on what the app is configured for?

Another thing the app (a task app) supports is multiple implementations of ITask, so I have a BasicTask, GTDTask, GoogleTask. So I was thinking I would need a repository method that could handle each implementation, and store the implementation in the correct cloud service. How do I achieve this abstraction with Unity? Is it best to just register all of the ITask types and have an abstract repository determine which type belongs to which repository based on the service the user is signed in to?

I want to keep the Page view models independent from the task implementation. I'll use DataTemplates that will have it's target type assigned to a specific task type. So the UI can stay loosely coupled and my view models are not tightly coupled with all of my repositories or implementations.

Thanks for any help.

Johnathon

Answer (score 0):

Register the implementations not a factory. The view model should never touch a repository. The controller uses the repository to get or update the model and provides it to the view model

Comment: By controller I assume you are referencing mvc? I'm using mvvm and WPF. Does that make a difference?

Comment: No mvvm benefits greatly from controller. The best implementation of mvvm I've found is model => business object, controller populate view model with command and initial values etc. View model is only the things the ui needs so collections of data and commands for buttons. The controllers aren't needed but they help code re use. I assume there will be multiple views where you see the same object. Having a controller providing the same command to each reduces testing and coding effort.

Comment: You're controller class would create delegate commands by passing them the work object such as update item on the controller and a method that dictates when the command is active

Comment: Still not sure I follow sorry. The view is databound to the view model, does the VM have a reference then to a controller object?

Comment: No i'd reference the VM from the controller. Instantiate the desired VM from controller passing the needed items in the constructor

Comment: But that works against Prism, which handles wiring up the VM with a matching View doesn't it?